# How to change one element's class depending on another's element position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, position, settimeout

I need to create a function checking if slider is in the certain left position. Depending on its position, I need to change another element's class. And it needs to be working **every time** slider's left position changes.
Everything works for me except the every time feature ;). Setting up setTimeout didn't help either...
Here's my code:

```
var $slider_pos = jQuery('.contentHolder').css('left');
var $slider_pos = $slider_pos || 0;
var $my_window = jQuery(window).width();
var $sensor = jQuery('.sensor');
function slideCheck(){
if($slider_pos == 0){
    $sensor.addClass('red');
} else if($slider_pos == $my_window * -1){
    $sensor.addClass('blue');
    $sensor.removeClass('red');
}
    setTimeout(slideCheck,500);
}
slideCheck();
```

Your help would be very appreciated for I've been strugling with this one for some time now.
 Thank you in advance!

Comment: Just call `slideCheck` every time the position changes????? `1. change position 2. slideCheck`???

Comment: How change the position of your element? drag and drop? click? Are you using any common silider?

Comment: I have to do this in Wordpress enviroment and I have to use Uber Slider plugin. Unfortunately, it is independent of me. It has set the autoplay time, can also be dragged or clicked to change a slide. It has no feature as adding a class to the active slide or something like this. The only thing that changes is the left position of the holder element, that's why I am trying to create that function this way. I hope my explanation helps.